# Initializing multiple python dictionaries to the same keynames and values

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to be able to loop through my main function and *bin* values to certain keys in these dictionaries. All six dictionaries have the same keynames but the dictionaries are unique. Is there a better way to 1. initialize all the dictionaries (i.e dictionary comprehension) or 2. store this data in a better way (i.e. nested dictionaries, namedtuples...)

Here is my current dictionary initialization:

```
TRI_1 = {'HF' : 0, 'NHF' : 0, 'TF' : 0, 'HM' : 0, 'NHM' : 0, 'TM' : 0}
TRI_2 = {'HF' : 0, 'NHF' : 0, 'TF' : 0, 'HM' : 0, 'NHM' : 0, 'TM' : 0}
TRV_1 = {'HF' : 0, 'NHF' : 0, 'TF' : 0, 'HM' : 0, 'NHM' : 0, 'TM' : 0}
TRV_2 = {'HF' : 0, 'NHF' : 0, 'TF' : 0, 'HM' : 0, 'NHM' : 0, 'TM' : 0}
TRV_3 = {'HF' : 0, 'NHF' : 0, 'TF' : 0, 'HM' : 0, 'NHM' : 0, 'TM' : 0}
TRV_4 = {'HF' : 0, 'NHF' : 0, 'TF' : 0, 'HM' : 0, 'NHM' : 0, 'TM' : 0}
```

EDIT: My Solution. I will remember g.d.d.c.'s method in the future but I need to have keys for the initial zero values so I can simply print TRI_1 and have {'key' : 0 } appear. This is a combination of Padraic's dictionary templating and Aleksi's comprehension. Thank you for the simple expandable solution!

```
TEMP = dict.fromkeys('HF NHF TF HM NHM TM'.split(), 0)
TRI_1, TRI_2, TRV_1, TRV_2, TRV_3, TRV_4 = ([dict(TEMP) for i in range(6)])
```

Comment: what is wrong with manually creating as you already have and what are you trying to do?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code above, it works. I was curious to know if there was another way to automatically create all the dictionaries since they all initialize to the same. TRI_1, TRI_2, ETC. = {} will not work. I am creating a place for instances of TRUE to be counted as I iterate through my main function (not provided) and I anticipate having more conditionals in my main function, increasing the number of dictionaries I will have.

Comment: Create one of the dictionaries, and then make copies?

Comment: Dictionaries have a `copy()` method to make shallow copies, so you could use it after creating the first one for dictionaries with immutable value (as appears to be the case here). For dictionaries with mutable values (like `list`s) you should use the `copy` module's `copy.deepcopy()` function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a template for dicts:

```
template_dict = {'HF': 0, 'NHF': 0, 'TF': 0, 'HM': 0, 'NHM': 0, 'TM': 0}

TRI_1,TRI_2={},{}
TRI_1.update(template_dict)
TRI_2.update(template_dict)
print TRI_1,TRI_2
{'TF': 0, 'NHF': 0, 'HM': 0, 'NHM': 0, 'HF': 0, 'TM': 0} {'TF': 0, 'NHF': 0, 'HM': 0, 'NHM': 0, 'HF': 0, 'TM': 0}
```

You can create new dicts and update them using the template  so you won't have to manually input the data each time you want a new dict.

Or simply:

```
TRI_1 = dict(template)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd use this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
container = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
```

Then you do this to tally:

```
container['TRV_1']['HF'] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy dictionaries by using:

```
new_dict = dict(old_dict)
```

If you're initializing all keys to the same values, you can also use:

```
new_dict = dict.fromkeys(keys, value)
```

That is, in this case:

```
template_dict = dict.fromkeys('HF NHF TF HM NHM TM'.split(), 0)
```

Although if the initial values are all the same, you can also use g.d.d.c's method, which creates everything automatically. The drawback of that method is that it might mask typos in dictionary keys easier, since it automatically creates new keys instead of raising an exception, but it obviously might make things easier for you. In the end, it all comes down to preference.